# How to order a looped list of calculated accuracies from highest to lowest?

Tags: python, loops

```
# Splitting into training and testing sizes

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], label_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

X_train looks like this:

```
566     deadly highly infectious avian flu forcing u f...
1546    join u today pm et citizencnn panel cost war f...
1676    troy kotsurs historymaking win full performanc...
2983    monday attack fox news crew reporting near ukr...
3203    louisiana state police hired outside consultan...
                              ...                        
905     mcdonalds bringing back spicy chicken mcnugget...
5192                      china name world hacking empire
3980    eu urgently discussing new sanction russia ukr...
235     hear offer ukrainian president zelensky made r...
5157    russia take measure decouple metallurgical pro...
Name: content, Length: 5141, dtype: object
```

Y_train - like this. The "label" are 0 and 1 meaning Fake News or Real News:

```
566     0
1546    0
1676    0
2983    0
3203    0
       ..
905     0
5192    1
3980    1
235     0
5157    1
Name: label, Length: 5141, dtype: int64
```

I have this loop to calculate predictions and their accuracies for a list of classifiers and I want to print the order by the accuracy results (from highest to lowest):

```
 # Show classification algorithm and accuracy

for name, classifier in models:
    print('\033[1m')
    print(name)
    classifier.fit(tfidf_X_train,Y_train)
    
    # Make predictions
    Y_pred = classifier.predict(tfidf_X_test)

    # Compute the scores
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
    print(f'\033[1mAccuracy\033[0m: {round(score*100,2)}%\n')
            
    #print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred))

    #print(metrics.classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred))
```

**This is what I get and want to be listed from Higher to Lower:**

```
Multinomial Naïve Bayes Classifier
Accuracy: 89.35%
        
Passive Aggressive Classifier
Accuracy: 89.35%
        
Linear Support Vector Classification
Accuracy: 90.05%
        
Logistic Regression Classifier
Accuracy: 88.88%
          
Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier
Accuracy: 89.74%
    
Random Forest Classifier
Accuracy: 89.81%
        
Decision Tree Classifier
Accuracy: 82.5%
        
K-Nearest Neighbours Classifier
Accuracy: 80.56%
```

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example (e.g. example values for `Y_test`, `Y_pred`, etc.).

Comment: It's too complicated. The dataframe is a list of tweets labelled Fake News or Real News (1,0)

Comment: It's rather difficult to help you if you don't provide the minimum necessary information for people to do so. At least try to provide dummy data.

Comment: You will have to store the score and the name in a list, then sort the list, then print the list.  Easy stuff.